# MySQL: Use Sysbench on Windows

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1, performance, performance-testing

Sysbench is a tool to analyze the MySQL performance. I downloaded it and extracted but there is no executable file. Files having extensions like `.sh` or `.c` or `.h` are available. I gone through the [documentation](http://sysbench.sourceforge.net/docs/#install). Even, I did not get any info about how to install and use this great tool on Windows machine?

Comment: Seems you need to compile that yourself

Answer (score 2):

You need to compile it yourself.

I downloaded the tarball and read the README-WIN.txt.  It certainly indicates that it can be compiled on Windows using CMake.